# Line touching a curve at a single point

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A straight line $y=2x-b$ touches a curve $y=3x^2+2$ at one point. What are the coordinates of the point of contact, and what is the value of $b$?

I don't know where to begin. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: The line is acting as a "tangent line", so its slope has to match the derivative of the function for the curve at the tangent point.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner I guess everybody will rush to this approach--but actually differentiation can (should?) be entirely avoided.

Comment: Somebody downvoted the problem, because we have all seen this type of "touches at one point, so slopes must match" concept a million times. But it is legit for the questioner not to have grasped that concept yet; he or she is calling for help on seeing what concept he/she is missing.  I would not downgrade this question at all.

Comment: @Did: The original question was tagged "derivatives", so I imagine that the intended method involves differentiating the curve. (Personally, I prefer that method for this particular question.)

Comment: @DivergentQueries Thanks (I had missed the tag). Then let me just mention that there is another method.

Answer (score 1):

If you "don't know where to begin," then the clue you are missing  is almost surely the matter of

*"What does it mean when we say that this line touches this curve at only one point?"*

If you draw a parabola and a line, they usually meet (if they meet at all) at two points.  There are just two ways to meet at exactly one point:

- The line might be the axis of the parabola (the line that slices it into two mirror-image halves) or parallel to that axis.
- The line might just barely touch the parabola at a point, never going from the outside to the inside.

In this case, the axis of the parabola is the Y axis (that is, it is a parabola pointing straight up) and the line $y=2x-b$ has slope $2$ so it is not going straight up.  So the first case can't be true here.

We look at the case of barely touching at a point, and here is the reason your book or professor posed this problem:  To just barely touch at a point, the **slope** of the line must match the **slope** of the parabola at that point.  That is the clue you were missing.

Since you are taking calculus, you know how to find the slope of the parabola at any point -- it is the derivative of $3x^2+2$.  The slope of the line is always $2$.  So you know where the line meets the parabola -- it is where 
$$
6x = 2 \\
y = 3x^2 + 2
$$

Finally, you have that point $(x,y)$ and you know that the line passes through it, so 
$$ 2x-b = y\\ b = 2x-y$$ and that finds $b$.

Answer (score 1):

this is a question involving nothing worse than conic sections, so calculus isn't needed.  Simple algebra suffices:  we look at the intersection(s) which occur when $$3x^2+2=2x - b\;\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;\;3x^2 - 2x + (2+b) = 0$$
You ask that there be only one solution to this, which means that the quadratic should have a double root.  This happens when the discriminant is 0...so we solve $$4 - 4*3*(2+b) = 0\;\;\;\Rightarrow\;\;\;b=-\frac 53$$
Once you have b the rest falls into place.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$y=3x^2+2\implies\dfrac{dy}{dx}=6x$$

$$\implies6x=2\iff x=?$$